# TTL get from ROW object of datastax java driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

How can we get TTL of a ROW returned from Cassandra.

Currently i am fetching TTL as part of Select cql query , e.g. SELECT NO,TTL;
And then using Row.getInt("TTL");

Is there any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTLs are set per cells and not rows. If you want to get 
select val, TTL(val) from test;
to show you the remaining TTL in seconds

For example

```
> insert into test (id, val) VALUES (uuid(), 'some value') using ttl 100;
> select val, TTL(val) from test;

 val           | ttl(val)
---------------+--------------
   hello world |      92
```

I executed the select query 8 seconds after inserting the row.

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement prep = session.prepare("SELECT val, TTL(val) from TABLE");
BoundStatement boundStmt = new BoundStatement(prep);
Row r = session.execute(boundStmt).one();
r.getInt("TTL(val)");
```

Will give you the TTL on the value in seconds.